# How to create an importable jar with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

here is my tree files:

```
-src
--tools
---Hammer.java
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

Here is my Hammer.java

```
package src.tools;

public class Hammer {
    public Hammer(){
        System.out.println("what time is it ?");
    }

    public void getTime(){
        System.out.println("Hammer time!");
    }
}
```

here is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'


// tag::repositories[]
repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}
// end::repositories[]

// tag::jar[]
jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'tools'
}
// end::jar[]


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'jskills',  
            'Implementation-Version': 1
    }
    //baseName = project.name + '-all'
    baseName = 'tools'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
// tag::dependencies[]
dependencies {
    implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile group: 'org.ejml', name: 'ejml-all', version: '0.41'
}
```

here is my settings.gradle

```
include 'tools'
```

How can i make a jar and import it in an other project to user the Hammer Class and it's function ?

It has no main function.

Regards

Comment: The main idea would be to just create the JAR file (via the `jar` or `fatJar` task), and then put that JAR file on the class-path/module-path of any other project that needs it. That would allow you to use the classes in the JAR file. Or are you asking how to publish the artifact to a repository?

Comment: @Slaw yes just create a jar to use it in an other project only with the jar file and not publishing it anywhere.

Comment: Then I'd expect simply building the JAR file and then adding it to your other projects should be sufficient.

Comment: @slaw is my gradle.build good ?

Comment: do you mean to try the Group, Artifact, Version route?